# print 1 to 100 without using recursion and conditions

Tags: code-golf, c

can we print **1 to 100** without using any if conditions and loops in c&c++?

Conditon:
main point is you must not use recursion...and doesnt hardcode code in it
for e.g

`print(1 2 3..etc);`

Comment: `print "1 to 100"` or `print 1 2 3 4 5 6 (etc)`?

Comment: @beary605 print 1 2 3..100

Comment: Does `goto` count?

Comment: Do preprocessor conditions count?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### C <strike>(90) (79) (59) (47) (42)</strike> (40)

<strike>static int</strike>

```
x=1;a(){char b[8];printf("%d\n",x++);b[24]-=5*(1-x/101);}main(){a();return 0;}
```

The function `a` which prints the numbers does not call itself! I exploited a buffer overflow and changed the return address to make the program counter go over function `a` again as long as I need.

I don't know if this is considered to be a recursion, but I thought it would worth trying.
This code works on my 64-bit machines with gcc 4.6, for other platforms the last statement of function `a`, could be a little different.

**Exp1:** I allocated a dummy buffer on stack `b`, and then addressed a passed-by-end location, which is the location of return address. I anticipated the distance between start of buffer and return address location from disassembly of function `a`.

**Exp2:** Expression `5*(1-x/101)`, is `5` for all `x<=100` and `0` for `x=101`. By looking at disassembly of `main` (in my case), if you decrease the return address by 5, you will set the PC to calling point of `a` again. In the updated codes, the return value of `printf` is used for checking loop condition.

**Update:** After applying [ugoren](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3544/ugoren)'s suggestions and some other changes:

```
x;a(){int b[2];b[3*(printf("%d\n",++x)&2)]-=5;}main(){a();}
```

**Update2:** After Removing function `a`:

```
x;main(){int b[2];b[6^printf("%d ",++x)&4]-=7;}
```

**Update3:**

```
x;main(b){(&b)[1|printf("%d ",++x)&2]-=7;}
```

**Update4:** Thanks to [mbz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395573/mbz) :)

```
x;main(b){(&b)[3|printf("%d ",++x)]-=7;}
```

Comment: Perhaps the most interesting answer here! Could you explain a bit about how it's supposed to work? How did you come with `b[24]` for the location of the PC and how can I determine what I should use instead (32-bit cygwin, gcc 4.7.3)? What is the rationale behind the magical expression 5*(1-x/101)?  

Also, is the `static` part of x's declaration needed? I'm not fully clear on how this works but since we aren't explicitly returning from a() wouldn't even an auto variable x remain in memory? And in this case it's even a global already.  

Thanks again for enlivening this dull repetitive thread.

Comment: @sundar Thank you for pointing out `static`. You're right, It was necessary for my previous code and I forgot to remove it. I added some small explanations, please check them out in answer :)

Comment: 1. `int b[2]` would be shorter. 2. `return 0;` isn't needed. 3. Changing the index on `b` instead of the subtracted value would be shorter. (of course, every such change could change machine code and break the solution, but I think it should be OK).

Comment: Another idea - maybe exploit the fact that `printf` returns a higher value at 100?

Comment: @saeedn Thanks for the explanations, it's very clear now. I felt stupid after reading Exp2 though, I'd been trying to decode it as some overcomplicated int-to-float bit pattern thing like the famous "inverse square root" formula, missed this much simpler explanation. :)

Comment: @ugoren Thanks for suggestions. I tried them. The `printf` return value idea was nice :)

Comment: `6^printf()&4` saves 2 chars. At 100, it changes `b[2]`, which is a harmless overflow on my machine. P.S. Why don't you change the character count in the title?

Comment: The net step is to get rid of `a`. `main` can do the work alone.

Comment: @ugoren I worked on `main` and updated the answer ;)

Comment: Nice. I used `-=4`, not `-=7`, but I guess both work. I was going to say it's done, but I saw your `\n`->` ` change, and decided not to give up. How about making `b` a parameter (and using `&b[...]`)?

Comment: @ugoren Yeah, that was good point. Unfortunately the parentheses around `&b` were necessary. I think it can't be shorter than this, can it?

Comment: It can be shorter. Try `%2d`. I couldn't get rid of the parenthesis. I tried the `x[y]`->`y[x]` trick, but it stays the same length (but even weirder than now).

Comment: @ugoren is there documentation somewhere for why that `x[y] -> y[x]` trick works? I remember that it works, but I don't remember why, and I can't find what to search for. (I know that it's equivalent to something which is the same as something else, which is the same as `y[x]`, but idr what those 2 middle ones are.)

Comment: @mbomb007, both are equivalent to `x[y]` = `*(x+y)` = `*(y+x)` = `y[x]`.

Answer (score 15):

## 85

C (gcc)

```
#define c printf("%d ",i++);
#define b c c c c c
#define a b b b b b
main(i){a a a a}
```

Assuming no command line arguments were passed.

Comment: Using the preprocessor is almost like hard coding it.

Comment: agreed. This is hardwired.

Answer (score 10):

### C++ (<s>159</s> 136)

With templates.

```
#include<cstdio>
#define Z(A,B,C,D)template<A>struct P B{P(){C;printf("%d ",D);}};
Z(int N,,P<N-1>(),N)Z(,<1>,0,1)int main(){P<100>();}
```

Comment: `s/class/struct/;s/public://;s/static //;s/::/()./g` saves 11 characters.

Answer (score 7):

### C <strike>71</strike> 70

Assuming the `?` operator is allowed.

```
#define f(a)a a a a a
int main(i){f(f(f(printf(i<102?"%d ":0,i++);)))}
```

Edit: `""`->`0`

If `?` is too similar to an if statement, then use this instead (78)

```
#define f(a)a a a a
#define g(a)f(a)a
int main(i){f(g(g(printf("%d ",i++);)))}
```

Comment: `?` is a conditional is it not?

Comment: vignesh4303 disallowed "if conditions", not all conditionals, which is why I included both answers.

Answer (score 3):

## 267

this is the best I can think of, assuming using the preprocessor is fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define a(i)i,i+1,i+2,i+3
#define b(i)a(i),a(i+4),a(i+8),a(i+12)
#define c(i)b(i),b(i+16)
#define e c(1),c(33)
#define f %d %d %d %d
#define g f f f f f f f f
#define r(m) #m
#define s(m) r(m)
int main(){printf(s(g g g f),e,c(65),a(97));return 0;}
```

Answer (score 3):

## C++ (115)

```
#include <cstdio>
template<int i>void p(){printf("%d ",i);p<i+1>();}
template<>void p<101>(){}
int main(){p<1>();}
```

Comment: Isn't this recursion?

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB/Octave, (5 chars)

```
1:100
```

Comment: Doesn't the question want a code in C?

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell (6 characters)

1..100

Comment: Equally doable, though no shorter, with `1..1e2`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 (25)

```
print(list(range(1,101)))
```

Comment: it is a inbuilt function that uses recursion!

Comment: I guess it depends on the interpreter if range uses recursion. **I** don't use recursion in my solution. I don't care if the inbuilt functions use recursion. If you want to take a look at every possible interpreter / compiler, you can't answer this question with anything else than assembly.

Comment: The garbage collector uses recursion!  So does the kernel of your OS.  So, computers are not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 (12)

```
>>> range(1,101)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby (11)  [non-competitive]

```
p *(1..100)
```

(Thanks to histocrat)

Previous 14-character solution:

```
p *1.upto(100)
```

This is a non-competitive answer (not C/C++ as requested)

Comment: `p *(1..100)` saves 3 characters.

Comment: @histocrat Thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: Can't you remove the brackets too?

Answer (score 0):

**Scala (22)**

```
1 to 100 foreach print
```

Comment: @downvoter care to comment ?

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6 (10)

```
print ^101
```

If one wants to be able to read the numbers and therefore spaces between the numbers would be nice, the following will do the trick.

```
say ~ ^101
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl (65)

Here's a non-trivial Perl approach (not like `say for 1 .. 100`). The program uses perl's regular expression engine to count its own characters (two times), and that's the reason why I couldn't golfify the content of `$k`. It tries to find a (minimal, non-greedy) group of arbitrary single characters until `(*FAIL)`.

```
$k='$k =~ /^(.+?)(?{print length($1) . "\n"})(*FAIL)/#'x2;eval$k;
```

The output is a list of all integers from 0 to 100 with newlines.

Comment: Clever solution on many levels, nice. I don't understand the `*FAIL` though, is it some special string to the regex engine? If not, won't the `*` have its usual metacharacter meaning here and mess things up?

Comment: @sundar see the ["Special Backtracking Control Verbs" section in perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) :)

Answer (score 0):

## Pygmy, (18 characters)

```
alert|[1 100].fill
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2 (39 chars)

```
p=lambda d:print d+1,;map(p,range(100))
```

## Python 3 (53 chars)

```
p=lambda d:print(d+1,end=' ');set(map(p,range(100)))
```

or print numbers on separate lines (28 char)

```
set(map(print,range(1,101)))
```

or (tested in Python 3.3.2, set items printing in ascending order - 24 chars)

```
print(set(range(1,101)))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Bash 13

```
echo {1..100}
```

Some more text so it posts.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

```js
alert([...Array(101).keys()].slice(1))
```

Creates an array of length 101, uses the spread operator to put the array keys (`0` to `100`) into an array, removes the first element (`0`) then `alert`s the numbers within the array.

Answer (score -1):

## Python - 61

Looping? No this is *list comprehension*.

```
d=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];print[x*10+y+1 for x in d for y in d]
```

Comment: That's stretching the "no hardcoding" pretty hard.

Answer (score -1):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 31 Bytes

```
func main()print(range(1, 100))
```

Run online and see expanded [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=3823e60014d9eddd70cc53277cd2a6d8)

Answer (score -1):

## JAVA, 52 chars

```
IntStream.range(1,101).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. I am not familiar with java but `forEach` looks an awful lot like a loop which seems to be forbidden by the challenge.

Comment: It's a stream function.  It performs an operation on each element of the stream.  It's not a loop.

Comment: I would disagree that a stream function is distinct from a loop but I don't think this argument is worthwhile.  This question has been closed as unclear for the very reason that "loop" is not very well defined.

Comment: This challenge restricts to C/C++, so Java is probably unacceptable here.